# How to stream value of Java List (Varargs) in a method?

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have the following method:

```
public static List<A> getValuesExclusion(A exclusion) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(item -> item != exclusion)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
//this function returns enum list of A types that has no A type'exclusion'
```

Now I want to make it into a list as argument:

```
public static List<A> getValuesExclusion(A... exclusions){
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(???)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

My question is, how can I do the filter for the second case? I would like to retrieve an enum list that excludes all the values "exclusions" as input. Here are the attributes of class A:

```
public enum A implements multilingualA{
    A("a"),
    B("b"),
    C("c"),
    D("d");
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is the relation between `A` and `AType`?

Comment: My apology, I mean A.Type, with Type = A, B, C, D

Comment: Are you sure you need a method for this?  [EnumSet.complementOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html#complementOf%28java.util.EnumSet%29) already does this.  For instance, `EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(A, C, D))`.

Comment: This method is used in different places with different values. I have not tried your approach, but it seems like a good way to implement. I'm practicing Java Stream 8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to make sure all the items are not included in the `exclusions` you could do:

```
public static List<A> getValuesExclusion(AType... exclusions){
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(e -> Arrays.stream(exclusions).noneMatch(c -> c == e))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Which will create a `Stream` of `exclusions` and then use `noneMatch()` to ensure the given `AType` is not included in the `Array`

Comment: Just one more question, is this solution efficient in terms of complexity/space?

Comment: @Jack usually, the number of `enum` constants and *vargargs* arguments are too small to make this relevant. But if you have a large number of constants and a large number of exclusion arguments, this would be very inefficient, having `O(n×m)` time complexity and holding an array containing all constants of this enumeration throughout the entire operation. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56108336/2711488) for a solution, not having these flaws. But as said, in practice, you rarely have number making this a relevant difference.

Answer (score 4):

You should rethink whether `List` really is the appropriate data type for something containing unique elements. A `Set` usually is more appropriate.

Then, if you care for performance, you may implement it as

```
public static Set<A> getValuesExclusion(A... exclusions){
    return exclusions.length == 0? EnumSet.allOf(A.class):
        EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(exclusions[0], exclusions));
}
```

The class `EnumSet` is specifically designed for holding elements of an `enum` type, just storing a bit for each constant, to tell whether it is present or absent. This allows operations like `complementOf`, which just flips all bits using a single ⟨binary not⟩ operation, without the need to actually traverse the `enum` constants.

If you insist on returning a `List`, you can do it as easy as

```
public static List<A> getValuesExclusion(A... exclusions){
    return new ArrayList<>(exclusions.length == 0? EnumSet.allOf(A.class):
        EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(exclusions[0], exclusions)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not go with `Stream`s here but with the a (imho) more readable approach:

```
public static List<A> getValuesExclusion(AType... exclusions){
    List<A> values = Arrays.asList(values());
    values.removeAll(Arrays.asList(ex));
    return values;
}
```

Comment: I'm practicing with Java Stream 8. However this is also a nice solution. Thank you!

Comment: You are using inconsistent names, `A` and `AType` should be the same type, apparently, and `values()` should be qualified with a class, unless you’re assuming to be inside of `A` (or `AType`). Likewise, it seems `exclusions` and `ex` are supposed to be the same. Then, there’s the problem that the list returned by `Arrays.asList` does not support removal of elements…